# Rails engine generate migration does not create migration file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines

I have just now started with Rails Engine.
I want to create migration files but it doesn't create any migration file in db/migrate folder.

When I hit command as,

```
rails g scaffold test name:string
```

it generates everything except migraions

ascratech@ascratech-desktop:~/Rohinee/demo_projects/blog$ rails g scaffold test name:string

```
  invoke  resource_route
   route    resources :tests
  invoke  scaffold_controller
  create    app/controllers/blog/tests_controller.rb
  invoke    erb
  create      app/views/blog/tests
  create      app/views/blog/tests/index.html.erb
  create      app/views/blog/tests/edit.html.erb
  create      app/views/blog/tests/show.html.erb
  create      app/views/blog/tests/new.html.erb
  create      app/views/blog/tests/_form.html.erb
  invoke    rspec
  create      spec/controllers/blog/tests_controller_spec.rb
  create      spec/routing/blog/tests_routing_spec.rb
  invoke      test_unit
  create        test/integration/blog/test_test.rb
  invoke    helper
  create      app/helpers/blog/tests_helper.rb
  invoke      rspec
  create        spec/helpers/blog/tests_helper_spec.rb
  invoke  assets
  invoke    js
  create      app/assets/javascripts/blog/tests.js
  invoke    css
  create      app/assets/stylesheets/blog/tests.css
  invoke  css
  create    app/assets/stylesheets/scaffold.css
```

why is this so?
How can I create migration file? or each time i need to create and copy it to db/migrate folder?

Comment: Do you have exist test table, I noticed that no migration file, and no model file (test.rb) in models folder ???

Comment: No. I was creating test scaffold which is not present in my rails engine